# Why do I encounter "TypeError: 'SchemaField' object is not iterable" when creating a table with BigQuery

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a requirement wherein I need to fetch metadata (table structure) from one of the BigQuery tables and, on that basis, create new tables. For example, [table 'Metadata' contains some table structures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw5S9.png).

In my Python script FileSubtype is passed dynamically from other script and on basis of it, column names and their corresponding datatypes would be fetched. And new tables will be created with these columns and datatypes.

Stuck part is, all these stuff has to be dynamic.

sample code (for testing purpose i have hardcoded the table name):

```
query1 = client.run_sync_query('%s limit 10' % QUERY)
query1.run()
rows = list(query1.fetch_data())
table = dataset.table('Sample_BQ_Table1')
for row in rows:
        print(row[0])
# Set the table schema
        table.schema = (
            bigquery.SchemaField(row[0], 'STRING'),
            )
table.create()
```

I am facing the error

> TypeError: 'SchemaField' object is not iterable`

while setting table schema.

Comment: Actually I am getting below error while executing my python script  :
**TypeError: 'SchemaField' object is not iterable**

Comment: Are you sure you have the trailing comma after `bigquery.SchemaField(...)` in your code? The error message indicates that you do not.

Answer (score 3):

The `table.schema` field expects an [iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9884259/101923), such as a list or tuple.

The code

```
table.schema = (
    bigquery.SchemaField(row[0], 'STRING')
)
```

would not set schema as an iterable, because plain parentheses don't create a tuple. The correct code would be

```
table.schema = (
    bigquery.SchemaField(row[0], 'STRING'),
)
```

Note the trailing comma.

Comment: Thx for the trailing comma note.